# ARC Welder cuts off the action bar

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

I just finished work on my first Android app, [New Daily Quotes](http://www.thevgc.net/new-daily-quotes). I was excited to hear that I could easily "port" it to Chromebooks and Google Chrome through ARC Welder and the Chrome Web Store, but I've run into a snag.

When I run the app in ARC Welder, the top portion of the action bar is cut off, making the title text impossible to read and the menu button difficult at best. The degree of cutoff varies depending on the form factor selected, with phone being the worst and tablet/maximized producing the same results. Below are screenshots of what I mean. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/darkwolffe/net.thevgc.quotes/blob/master/main/java/net/thevgc/quotes/MainActivity.java) if it helps any.

**Phone UI**

[image: Droid RAZR]

**ARC Welder Phone UI - Landscape**

[image: ARC Welder Phone UI - Landscape]

**ARC Welder Phone UI - Portrait**

[image]

Comment: Can you try hierarchyviewer to see if there is something unexpected?  You need to enable adb (open the app's page from chrome://extension and run plugin.shell('adbd') on non-ChromeOS).  Or you can [file a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) with steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!

Turns out, using ARC Welder (at least currently) returns API 19 (KitKat), and because I was using [jgilfelt's SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library, it was setting a nonexistent status bar tint directly over the top of the action bar.

I was able to fix the issue by not only checking to ensure that we are in fact on API 19, but also that the manufacturer build doesn't contain *chromium* in the contents.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 19 && !Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("chromium")) { ... }
```